# Where to find the value inside get_option function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code snippet inside the header.php file in my WP directory:

```
                    <div class="top_menu_right">

                    <?php

                        $pp_top_right_content = get_option('pp_top_right_content');

                        echo html_entity_decode(stripslashes($pp_top_right_content));

                    ?>

                </div>
```

My question is where can find the value of the variable

```
(pp_top_right_content)
```

inside the 
`get_option` function

I am a newbie in WordPress coding and would very much appreciate response to my question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to save option using `update_option` earlier to get value from `get_option`.

Comment: @Nilambar that code is working. I just need to find where to get the value of pp_top_right_content since I need to change the value being displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in the wp_options table gets stored in the serialized array format in the option_value field.

Try searching in the option_value field.

Comment: You mean stored in WP database under wp_options table?